# Search for a variable in Datawarehouse (Postgresql)

Tags: postgresql, variables, search, command, data-warehouse

I have the proper name of the variable I am looking for: ab_testing__x but there are several tables in the datawarehouse. Is there a command that helps you to quickly identify in which tables this variable is stored?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `information_schema` tables:

```
select table_schema, table_name 
  from information_schema.columns
 where column_name = 'ab_testing__x';
```